# using a pattern in html input for just numbers and N/A

Tags: html, regex

Struggling to get the correct formatting for a regex which will accept any number or N/A any other value would fail validation. The following did not work. My regex is less than average...

```
<input type="text" record="job" name="quote_design_hours" size="6" pattern="[0-9|N/A]" title="Value must be a number or N/A" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern should be `(N/A|[0-9]+)`

[Here is an example in action](https://regex101.com/r/HhoItm/1)

The reasoning is:

- value should match one of two expressions so you use OR operator `|` (you can use non-matching groups with `(?: ... | ... )` instead
- first expression is literally `N/A`
- second expression is any digit `[0-9]` (i.e. any character from `0` to `9`), and can be present one or more times (`+`)

Comment: They are anchored by default.

Comment: Right, `N/A|[0-9]+` will do. `pattern="^(N/A|[0-9]+)$"` will be translated into `^(?:^(N/A|[0-9]+)$)$` pattern. It will also work, but it is rather redundant.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my comment, I wasn't aware of this detail